# CMake - Alternative to generator expression for build output directory?

Tags: build, cmake

I have a cmake build system gone wild. Before supporting IDEs, everything was ok.

I need to copy files (shaders in this case) to the build directory. They need to be copied when they've changed, regardless of whether the main target is built or not.

I had success before, as I could add a custom command with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`, add dependencies later and everything was fine.

The problem is, when using a generator expression for the command output, it creates a dependency from my custom command to the main target. This means adding a dependency backwards (which is needed to trigger the copy) throws an error because of cyclic dependencies.

This is what I have so far, which doesn't work because the custom target (thus custom command) is not triggered when the main target doesn't need rebuilding.

```
set(SHADER_IN_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/shaders)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SHADERS "${SHADER_IN_DIR}/*.glsl")

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/shaders/)

set(STAMP_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/.stamps)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${STAMP_DIR})

set(STAMP_FILES "")
foreach(SHADER ${SHADERS})
    get_filename_component(SHADER_FILENAME ${SHADER} NAME)

    set(STAMP_FILE ${STAMP_DIR}/${SHADER_FILENAME}.stamp)

    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${STAMP_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${STAMP_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${SHADER} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/shaders/${SHADER_FILENAME}
        DEPENDS ${SHADER}
    )

    list(APPEND STAMP_FILES ${STAMP_FILE})
endforeach()

add_custom_target(Shaders
    SOURCES ${SHADERS}
    DEPENDS ${STAMP_FILES})

# Need to add dependency here! But I can't :(
```

So, is there any other way to get what output directory will be used in an IDE? All "solutions" I've read to force building a target have failed (they pretty much all rely on `add_dependencies`).

Thank you for saving my sanity.

Comment: Why don't you use `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` instead of  `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>`?

Comment: CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR doesn't work for IDEs. They place binaries inside Debug/ or Release/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, instead of trying to find out where the IDE is going to output the binary, I forced output in a predictable bin/ dir.

```
set(BINARY_OUT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_OUT_DIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_OUT_DIR})
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_OUT_DIR})

foreach(OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
    string(TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${BINARY_OUT_DIR})
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${BINARY_OUT_DIR})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${BINARY_OUT_DIR})
endforeach(OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
```